# Show message only when there are no messages for other components

Tags: forms, validation, jsf-2, user-interface, primefaces

I have 3 messages displayed when validating the form, kind of this :

```
<p:message id="msgCity1"  for="city1" styleClass="required" display="text" />
<p:message id="msgCity2"  for="city2" styleClass="required" display="text" />
<p:message id="msgCountry"  for="msgCountry" styleClass="required" display="text" />
```

the first(msgCity1) and second(msgCity2) messages are validated on event (keyup)
the last one is validate on server side, I would like to show the last message (msgCountry), if the validation is ok for the first 2 messages, I mean if the message are empty,

For that I would like to use rendered on the last message but I do not how I can get the value of the first 2 message in xhtml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather hook on [`UIInput#isValid()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIInput.html#isValid%28%29) directly than on the presence of a message for the input.

E.g.

```
<h:inputText id="city1" binding="#{city1}" ... />
<h:inputText id="city2" binding="#{city2}" ... />
...
<p:message for="msgCountry" ... rendered="#{city1.valid and city2.valid}" />
```